# lplfitch package and math environment

Tags: math-mode

I would like to write letters in math mode, that is in italic, into proofs without using a lot of \textit{} (by the way, $$ doesn't work into proofs environment).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\begin{document}
\fitchprf{\pline[1.]{Fa}}{\ellipsesline \\
\pline[5.]{Q}
         
 }
\end{document}
```

Produces this

[image: lpfith standard]

but I would need this instead:

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is the line

```
\newcommand*{\formula}[1]{\ensuremath{\sf{#1}}}
```

which, by the way, uses the command `\sf` that has been deprecated for a quarter of a century.

Solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lplfitch}

\renewcommand*{\formula}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}


\begin{document}

\fitchprf{\pline[1.]{Fa}}{
  \ellipsesline \\
  \pline[5.]{Q}
 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day